# Futures Derived From Contents of Collection

Tags: scala, future, scala-collections

Imagine a function that returns a `Future` like this.

```
def findById(Int id): Future[MyObject]
```

And I have a collection of ids.

```
val ids = Vector(1,2,3)
```

What is the most idiomatic way to iterate over the collection and call the function for each value *in parallel* to produce (effectively) this?

```
val result: Vector[Future[MyObject]] = Vector(findById(1), findById(2), findById(3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simple `map` is enough: `ids.map(findById)`, or more lengthy `ids.map(id => findById(id))`

Consider following example code:

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import concurrent.duration._
import concurrent.{Await, Future}


def findById(id: Int): concurrent.Future[String] = concurrent.Future { Thread.sleep(3000); "OK" }
val ids = Vector(1,2,3)
val sequenced = Future.sequence(ids.map(findById)) // we sequence them so we can wait for one future of a collection, not collection of futures
Await.result(sequenced, 10.seconds) // you probably don't want to block normally, but this is for tests it should be resolved in about 3 seconds, so it runs in parallel
```

You can run it in REPL (just run `scala` and execute `:paste`).

Comment: @Vidya All of the futures are created immediately, and thus start executing immediately in parallel.

Comment: @Vidya check an example I've attached. I think you're confused by for comprehension, but there the futures are not created in parallel because the for comprehension is translated to nested `map` / `flatMap` invocations.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a note, `sequenced` here has type `Future[Vector[String]]`, which is what OP almost certainly meant, even though he asked for `Vector[Future[String]]`